# TypeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite, django-admin

I use in my models.py

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    data_pedido = models.DateField('Data do pedido')
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
```

but runserver and add date via admin

show this message.

I use sqlite3.

[image]

[image]

See my project in [github](https://github.com/rg3915/banco_de_dados/tree/master/pedido/pedido_project)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `__unicode__` methods need to return a Unicode string, not a `datetime.date` object. So you should adapt the following to return Unicode:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.data_pedido
```

For example:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.data_pedido)
```

Or you can format the date using a [formatting method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).