# datetime TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, strptime

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import datetime

someday = datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 23, 0, 0)

someday = datetime.datetime.strptime(someday[:10], '%Y-%m-%d')
print someday
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  If it's just "get the date part of a datetime," you can use the `.date()` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute '\_\_getitem\_\_'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831994/typeerror-datetime-date-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`someday` is a `datetime` object, which does not support slicing.  So, doing `someday[:10]` raises a `TypeError`.

You need to convert `someday` into a string before you slice it:

```
someday = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(someday)[:10], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> someday = datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 23, 0, 0)
>>>
>>> someday  # This is a datetime object
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 23, 0, 0)
>>> someday[:10] # Does not support slicing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
>>> str(someday) # This returns a string
'2014-09-23 00:00:00'
>>> str(someday)[:10] # Supports slicing
'2014-09-23'
>>>
```

Comment: The conversions to and from string are unnecessary here. Just [use `print someday.date()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27987553/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - My answer was mainly focused on why the OP's slice was failing and how to get it working (with slicing).  However, I agree that calling `.date()` is a lot more pythonic in this case.  +1 for mentioning it. :)

Answer (score 1):

`someday` is not a string therefore you won't get the substring by applying `[:10]`. It is a `datetime` object.

To get the date from the `datetime` object, just call `.date()` method:

```
print someday.date()
```

No need to convert to convert `someday` to string using `str()` only to convert it immediately back using `datetime.strptime()`.