# Django: TypeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I have TransactionForm as follows:

```
class TransactionForm(ModelForm):
   start_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
   duration = forms.ChoiceField(choices=duration_choices)
   class Meta:
      model=Transaction
      fields=(
         'start_date',
         'duration',
         ) 

   def clean(self):
      date = self.cleaned_data.get("start_date")

      if date < datetime.date.today():
         raise forms.ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
      return date
```

It has a method clean which checks if date entered is at least todays or greater. When some date in past is inserted it shows error on remplate as expected. But when a valid date is entered, I get the following error.

> 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'get'

Here is my view.py file

```
def packages(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = completeForm(req.POST)
        tf = TransactionForm(req.POST)

        if tf.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("Some page")
        else:
            errorList = tf.errors['__all__']
            args={'form':form, 'errors':errorList, 'tf':tf}
            return render(req,'main/common/packages.html',args)

    else:   
        form =  completeForm()
        tf = TransactionForm()
        args={'form':form, 'counter':1, 'tf':tf}
        return render(req,'main/common/packages.html',args)
```

If I remove clean method from form it works fine but I need to validate date without using JavaScript validation.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831994/typeerror-datetime-date-object-has-no-attribute-getitem) question closest to mine but its solution is not working or me. Could you please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't validate over multiple fields, thus I suggest trying this instead of def clean(self):

```
def clean_start_date(self):
    st_date = self.cleaned_data.get("start_date")

    if st_date < datetime.date.today():
        raise forms.ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
    return st_date
```

Edit: If you did try to validate over multiple fields, that would be the case when [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) suggests using custom clean function.

Comment: Hi Mxle, Thanks a lot for your quick response. It is working. but could you please explain why it was not working when I was overriding clean method? What exactly has made the difference here?

Comment: My idea is that was because you used _date_ word for a variable. Using such words (and, list, dict, etc) may cause all sorts of magical errors.